# How to bind inputs and outputs for dynamically created components using `ngTemplateOutlet`?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

I need to create host component which takes components, to render inside a `mat-tab`. Components are provided inside a list and it can be vary. Since we don't know which component to render, how can we bind inputs and outputs with the parent (host) view and dynamically created component.

Ex:

```html
<div *ngFor="let tab of tababList">
 <mat-tab *ngIf="tab.isVisible">
  <ng-template mat-tab-label>{{tab.title|translate}}</ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tab.component"></ng-container>
 </mat-tab>
</div>
```

For alternative approach I've considered `ViewContainerRef` with `ComponentFactoryResolver` method. In this way `ViewContainerRef` got undefined since `*ngIf` was there and can't add more tabs.

Any solutions to this matter?

I have referred [Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet#description)

Comment: You can pass properties to the template via the outlet.